# z index and position relative

Tags: css, z-index

w3c Says that z-index "Only works on positioned elements(position: absolute;, position: relative; or position: fixed;)."

I see it works in absolute position: http://jsfiddle.net/WwXVV/2/
But why not in relative position: http://jsfiddle.net/WwXVV/

Can anyone explain why in relative position and in this specific case the div with the higher z-index is not on top?

CSS:

```
#top {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    z-index:1; 
}

#bottom {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100px; height:100px;
    background-color:blue; 
    z-index:0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply floating them next to one another. Apply `left` to the bottom div:

```
#bottom { left: -100px; }
```

What this will do is "position" the bottom div under the top one. Applying relative position by itself won't do anything, you need to start moving the target element around to see the stacking effect.

If you are wondering about absolute positioning, it works differently. Absolute positioning takes the element out of document flow (meaning it won't affect the layout of other elements), and by default puts it at the top left of its first ancestor that doesn't have a value of `position:static`, so both your elements stacked on top of each other.

Comment: I understand the absolute position and z-index, but not relative position and z-index. If the z-index puts #top on another layer in the stack there is an empty space behind that should be occupied by the #bottom. What am I missing?

Comment: Relatively positioned elements are *not* removed from flow.  Without an adjustment via the top/right/bottom/left properties, there is no difference between a static and relatively positioned element in terms of the space it occupies on the page.  That is why `#top` will not overlap `#bottom` in your relative positioning example.

Comment: In your example, you are floating your two elements next to each other, so while they may be on different layers in the visual stack, they aren't overlapping. You need to apply some other style like `left`, `right`, or a margin to bump one of the elements over so they overlap, and then you will see the z-index being applied.

Answer (score 0):

You have `float`ed both elements to the left. They don't overlap, hence `z-index` doesn't do anything.

If you add `margin-left: -20px` to the right box, you'll see the desired effect.

Comment: Ok I understand your answer to make it work. But I think I am confused about the concept of z-index. w3c says:"The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element" so I thought that  it means the 2 divs where in different "layers", so the float should make them put in the same position?

Comment: `z-index` is only applicable when elements overlap. When they don't, it doesn't matter. You're basically hinting at the rendering engine what you want to be on top or not. If nothing overlaps, the rendering engine has noted that the element should be on top of others, but doesn't have anything to put it on top of.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, with `position:relative` and `float:left;` the divs will be next to each other. With `position: absolute` they will ignore `float:left;` and will put both element on the same spot, using z-index to show who is in front.

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index) is just relevant when the boxes overlap visually.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Relative Positioning, z-index working fine. Try this code

```
  #top {
       position:relative;
       top:20px;
       left:0px;
       width:100px; height:100px;
       background-color:yellow;
       z-index:1; 
       }

 #bottom {
      position:relative;
      top:0px;
      left:30px;
      width:100px; height:100px;
      background-color:blue; 
      z-index:0;
      }
```

In case of Absolute Positioning

```
 #top {
       position:absolute;
       top:0px;
       left:20px;
       top:0; left:0;
       width:100px; height:100px;
       background-color:yellow;
       z-index:1; 
      }

 #bottom {
          position:absolute;
          top:20px; left:50px;
          width:100px; height:100px;
          background-color:blue; 
          z-index:0;
         }
```

Comment: But if the z-index puts the top in another layer of the stack, it leaves an empty space behind. If the position relative puts the bottom element in the flow. Shouldn't that make the #bottom occupy that empty space in the flow?